# jquery mobile web app leave empty white space at page bottom

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I have a web app (i used JQM) currently customized to iphone.

all elements are fitted to the page height, but i'm getting a white space on the page bottom.

when viewing the page on pc browser everything is fine, so i guess the problem is related to the iphone screen resolution configuration on some CSS file.

**Please view the web page on your iPhone to see the white space (scroll down)**:
http://aspspider.org/elimiz/check4/MC_v1.0.htm

Help me

Comment: Doubt that it's iPhone-only, because I have the same with my Phonegap-Android-app using jQuery Mobile. Hope somebody knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing the issue on my iPhone but it sounds like a problem I had on a site.
I fixed it by setting a wrapper surrounding all the content as overflow: hidden. It might take some trial and error to find which element to put this on, and you might need to define height values on elements that dont have height explicitly stated.

Comment: Added the suggested `overflow: hidden` to the body element and it worked like a charm. Good call.